# How to convert subword PPL to word level PPL?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert, language-model

I'm using this formula to covert subword perpexity to word perplexity:
`PPL_word = exp(log(PPL_subword) * num_subwords / num_words)`
The question is do I need to include the [SEP] and [CLS] tokens when counting subwords?